# output of stargazer causing rmarkdown to fail

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm trying to compile this .rmd to pdf and I keep getting a latex error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile 2020-07-23_a.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See 2020-07-23_a.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

If I remove this table generated by stargazer it compiles to pdf:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Tue, Dec 08, 2020 - 10:50:52 PM
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & a & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
1 & a & $0.190$ & $1.314$ & $$-$7$ & $1$ & $1,047.041$ & $$-$14.031$ & $$-$146.912$ \\ 
2 & b & $0.168$ & $1.484$ & $$-$1$ & $1$ & $997.999$ & $$-$5.740$ & $$-$57.288$ \\ 
3 & c & $0.242$ & $1.033$ & $$-$4$ & $0$ & $974.519$ & $$-$6.615$ & $$-$64.467$ \\ 
4 & d & $0.245$ & $1.021$ & $$-$3$ & $1$ & $997.918$ & $$-$8.568$ & $$-$85.500$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

What about this table is causing an error?

edit, reprex:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: ''
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 10
    fig_width: 15
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 10
    fig_width: 15
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
geometry: margin=0.9in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{color}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhf{}
- \lhead{`r Sys.Date()`}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
- \rfoot{\thepage}
- \lfoot{\hyperlink{page.1}{$\Uparrow$}}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
- \setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
fontsize: 6pt
classoption: landscape
---

<!--
Comments
Version: 2017-06-05
-->

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

 tblSummary =structure(list(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), d = c(0.190284983522521, 
0.168477173924889, 0.242036289808836, 0.244817676726466), e = c(1.31381885933427, 
1.48388054106045, 1.03290295929364, 1.02116809269179), f = c(-7, 
-1, -4, -3), g = c(1, 1, 0, 1), h = c(1047.04137748695, 997.998686454919, 
974.519473047256, 997.918457406374), i = c(-14.0312028883339, 
-5.74023801609359, -6.61528084178918, -8.56783431205567), j = c(-146.9125, 
-57.2875, -64.4672, -85.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
 
 stargazer::stargazer(tblSummary, summary = FALSE)
 
```
````

Comment: The LaTeX code looks fine. Maybe some packages required for compiling to PDF are missing but it's hard to tell without the (.Rmd) source. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: thanks @M.A., added the .Rmd

Answer (score 2):

One option is to mark the output as latex:

````
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = F}
cat("```{=latex}")
stargazer( tblSummary, summary = FALSE,type = "latex", header = FALSE)
cat("```")
```
````